# Proof of a famous theorem in multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How do I prove the following famous theorem using simple calculus:

$\int\dfrac{d}{dt}f(t,x)dx=\dfrac{d}{dt}\int f(t,x)dx$

or how is it that by first differentiating and then integrating a multi-variable function yields the same function as by first integrating and then differentiating that multi-variable function.

Comment: Check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: This requires some restrictions on $f$, and can be proved with real analysis.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{d}{dt} \int\limits_a^{b} f(t,x)dx
&=\dfrac{\int\limits_a^{b} f(t+dt,x)dx-\int\limits_a^{b} f(t,x)dx}{dt}\\
&=\dfrac{\int\limits_a^{b} \left[ f(t,x)+\partial f_{t}(t,x)\right] dx-\int\limits_a^{b} f(t,x)dx}{dt}\\
&=\dfrac{\int\limits_a^{b} \left[ f(t,x)+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x) dt\right] dx-\int\limits_a^{b} f(t,x)dx}{dt}\\
&=\dfrac{\int\limits_a^{b} \left[ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x) dt\right] dx}{dt} 
& & \text{(since}\int\limits_a^{b} f(t,x)dx& & \textrm{is common)}\\
&=\int\limits_a^{b}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,x) dx
\end{align}
(since we are integrating with respect to dx, we can factor out dt and cancel it with dt in the denominator)